# i want to merge three tables by joing but I am getting rows duplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, join, gridview

```
 <asp:Panel ID = "Panel1" runat="server" ScrollBars="Auto">
    <asp:GridView ID = "GridView2" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceDelete" DataKeyNames="IvrDataid,dayid,menudataid">
       <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField = "IvrDataid" HeaderText="IvrDataid" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="IvrDataid" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField = "ivrName" HeaderText="ivrName" SortExpression="ivrName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField = "loginid" HeaderText="loginid" SortExpression="loginid" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField = "countrycode" HeaderText="countrycode" SortExpression="countrycode" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField = "greetingtext" HeaderText="greetingtext" SortExpression="greetingtext" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField = "contactnumber" HeaderText="contactnumber" SortExpression="contactnumber" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField = "starttime" HeaderText="starttime" SortExpression="starttime" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField = "endtime" HeaderText="endtime" SortExpression="endtime" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField = "loginid1" HeaderText="loginid1" SortExpression="loginid1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField = "ivrName1" HeaderText="ivrName1" SortExpression="ivrName1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField = "dayy" HeaderText="dayy" SortExpression="dayy" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField = "ivrNumber" HeaderText="ivrNumber" SortExpression="ivrNumber" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField = "mainMenuNum" HeaderText="mainMenuNum" SortExpression="mainMenuNum" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField = "mainMenuText" HeaderText="mainMenuText" SortExpression="mainMenuText" />
        </Columns>                                                         
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID = "SqlDataSourceDelete" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IvrContext %>" 
        SelectCommand="  SELECT * FROM IvrDatas INNER JOIN menudatas ON 
        IvrDatas.ivrName = menudatas.ivrName AND IvrDatas.loginid = menudatas.loginid
    INNER JOIN days ON
        IvrDatas.loginid = days.loginid AND IvrDatas.ivrName = days.ivrName
                where IvrDatas.loginid = @lemail  "> 
        <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name = "lemail" QueryStringField= "lemail" Type= "String" />
        </ SelectParameters >
    </ asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Panel>
```

I want to merge three tables using join in gridview  but problem is that I am getting duplications of rows as i should get 6 rows from 3 tables overe all after joining but I am getting more rows

Answer (score 0):

Joins generally do create multiple rows when there is many-to-one relationship. You must handle it as appropriate for your use case - usually with GROUPing and subqueries. But since you only seem to be displaying data from one of the tables, you can probably take the easy way out and use `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0):

SelectCommand="SELECT IvrDatas.*, days.*, menudatas.* FROM IvrDatas INNER JOIN days ON 
                               IvrDatas.loginid = days.loginid AND IvrDatas.ivrName = days.ivrName INNER JOIN menudatas ON 
                               IvrDatas.loginid = menudatas.loginid AND IvrDatas.ivrName = menudatas.ivrName where IvrDatas.loginid = @lemail"

// THIS SELECT QUERY WORKING FINE and it is fetching reqiured records by joining 3 tables